# Django queries spanning foreign key

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    # some fields here ...

class Entry(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, reverse_name="entries")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I want to query all `Collection`s that have at least one `Entry` associated which I do with (quite quirky, I think):

```
collections_qs = Collection.objects.annotate(
    entry_count=Count('entries')
).filter(entry_count__gt=0)
```

Which works quite well. But I want to combine this query with a date/time window search given by the two `datetime`s `start` and `end`. What I've come up with was:

```
if start:
    collections_qs = collections_qs.filter(entries__start_time__gte=start)
if end:
    collections_qs = collections_qs.filter(entriess__end_time__lte=end)
```

But that just rearranges the order of the returned `Collection`s but not the content. How can I achieve the date/time search (preferably with just one query)?

Comment: For the first thing, `Collection.objects.filter(entries__isnull=False)` is somewhat weird but should work.

Comment: For the second thing, do you want collections for which _all_ entries verify the dates conditions, or for which at least _one_ entry verifies them?

Comment: (also for the first thing adding `distinct()` to the queryset should be necessary to avoid having collections repeated `n` times where `n` is the number of entries they have)

Comment: Ah, should have made that one clearer. As you say, I want all `Collections` that have at least one `Entry` in that time window. Your suggestions are helpful, but I still don't know how to perform the time query ...

Comment: OK there must be something I missed because what you've come up with should work. Are you sure the returned collections don't match your conditions? Some remarks : 1. if you apply a filter on start and/or end, you shouldn't need to have the first filter (`annotate` or `entries__isnull`). 2. For reverse FK, there is a difference between `.filter(a=b, x=y)` and `filter(a=b).filter(x=y)` (see [doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) ). This remark only applies to the end/start condition: what you need is the `filter(., .)` one.

Comment: @Arthur: that was it! I had to use `filter(first, second)` to get what I wanted. If you want to earn some reputation please go ahead and create an answer that I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reverse FK (and ManyToMany fields too), there is a difference between

`.filter(a=b, x=y)` and `.filter(a=b).filter(x=y)` (see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)).

What you need when you have both `start` and `end` conditions is the `filter(.,.)` one that will get you the `Collections` that have at least one `Entry` that verifies both condition.

Also, `Collection.objects.filter(entries__isnull=False).distinct()` seems more readable than `.annotate(entry_count=Count('entries')).filter(entry_count__gt=0)`.

Finally, when you have at least one condition on `entries`, you don't need to have any filter to check for the existence of such entries.